# Question changed after two months and answer unaccepted

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

About two months ago I answered a question, received a few upvotes, and the answer was accepted. Today I saw that my answer was unaccepted so I looked at the question to see if another answer had been accepted. No other answer was accepted however the OP had changed their question to something completely new.

The OP said he changed the question because he lost the ability to post new questions, to which a moderator later replied that his account was blocked due to low quality answers. So my question is, can I get the original question rolled back and my accepted answer accepted again since the only reason it was unaccepted is because the OP was trying to circumvent the block on his account?

Specific question: [Where is an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091606/where-is-an-error)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the question was changed drastically, then yes, you have every right to roll back to its original version. If the OP openly admitted that he only edited the question because he couldn't ask new ones, I'd be a tiny bit surprised if the moderator didn't roll it back already. Usually you'd want to try and leave a message in the edit reason explaining why the rollback was issued.

If the OP keeps trying to resend the edits to change the question, it will get flagged for an editing war and moderators will have to take a closer look at it.

However, there is no possible way to get the accepted answer re-instated. Only the OP can do that and if they never do it, then there's nothing you can really do about it.

Comment: Looks like the original question and points have all been returned to normal (sans accepted answer). Thanks to those that helped.

Comment: @j08691 - As an aside, this meta post as brought some attention to your correct answer, which means you'll probably earn a few more upvotes to make up for the unjustified unaccept.

Answer (score 4):

If this is true, I would just flag the question for a moderator. Just leave a note in the little box that comes up.

> [image: Flagging - Leaving a Note]

Comment: I did do that once I discovered what had happened. Seems like aside from the answer being re-accepted, things are back to normal.