# Can I replace an old question by editing it?

Tags: support, questions, edits, old-questions

I have asked some simple questions, that maybe were too easy, because I got downvotes on these. After I learned more I found my questions were really easy.

I wonder if I could replace some old questions with other, entirely different questions by editing them. That means, I change the old question. Is that appropriate? Because I don't know how to improve the question that got downvoted, it's too easy, there is no wrong to correct.

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) [Rolling back a completely changed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question) [Question changed after two months and answer unaccepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134401/question-changed-after-two-months-and-answer-unaccepted)

Comment: You could ask SE to anonymize the questions so they're no longer associated with tour account.

Comment: why I got so many downvotes here?isn't it proper?

Comment: @Winnie [Voting on Meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, don't change old questions whole-sale, that would be a disservice to those who tried to help you answer them.

You are not doing too badly on Stack Overflow. Leave those old questions be; at most, if there are no upvoted answers, you could delete them.

Comment: Deleting questions isn't a good idea. This can lead to a question ban much faster than just a couple downvotes. Also, deleted questions have no opportunity to be edited, improved, and *then* upvoted.

Comment: @jmort253: when all you do is deleting questions, then that's not a good idea. The OP has two out of *twelve* questions that have been downvoted, and has upvoted answers to boot. No way the OP is in danger of triggering the ban heuristics.

Comment: @ jmort253 I want to improve the old one either ,but I can't find how  to improve,after I learn more I think my question is simply too,that's also the reason why question got downvote,I think.

Comment: Just be careful not to go on a delete-spree, this won't help you if you do it too much.

Comment: I really even don't know there is an delete option for OP

Comment: @jmort253 now I want to change this question to "how to improve the question that's too easy"

Comment: @Winnie - if the question has no upvoted answers you can delete it.

Comment: @ChrisF OK ,i see

Comment: @MartijnPieters Will deleting questions help to lift a ban?

Comment: @DibyaRanjan: NO, it won't. That is, from what we can make out, the ban heuristics score deleted posts with negative scores against you, deleting more will only make that worse.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In this link http://goo.gl/C1Kwu it has stated that fix you question before doing anything so its almost obvious that the user will try to modify the question. Some times user tries too much and changes the whole question

Comment: @DibyaRanjan: That doesn't mean it's a good idea to do so. 'Fixing your question' could be an uphill struggle for some, if the original premise of the question is terrible.

Comment: Yes but if some other ways are there to lift ban then you could tell so that users will not modify their questions and start doing.

Answer (score 5):

Fix your questions in any way you see fit, but still *keeping the original meaning*.

Even if they are downvoted now, you can still fix this. Sometimes what makes a difference between a question being upvoted or downvoted into oblivion is the **wording**. There are questions that would have otherwise be downvoted/closed/deleted be accepted, just because the wording made the trick. And I've used that trick myself.

Deleting the question is a choice but is not suggested if:

- you do it too often or too much
- there already are answers

If you delete too many questions, you're going to trigger the question ban and it's better to avoid it.

Look at your questions, can you improve the wording without changing the fundamental question behind it? Can you add detail? Context? Some prior research? If you don't know what to do with them even after trying, you can ask a Meta question looking for help. Or you can go to chat.

You'll always find someone who can help you fix and improve your question. This might get you upvotes in the long run and not to mention that the question will get bumped and this will cause users to see the fixes, re-considering their votes and even reverting them to upvotes.

Comment: I 'm confuse about why I got so many downvotes now.Is it not proper here?

Comment: @Winnie Check under your question for the answer.